# Access this in Firebase Angular2 promise

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, es6-promise

I'm playing with Firebase in Angular2 and I'm stuck accessing `this` in a promise.

Here is my script. For context understanding: at login, I wanna check the basic data in the database related to this user are still current.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, FirebaseAuthState, FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  user;
  userUID;
  userEmail;
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

 constructor(public af: AngularFire, @Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
   this.af.auth.subscribe(authState => {
      if (authState && !authState.auth.isAnonymous) {
        this.user = authState;
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.userEmail = this.user.auth.email;
        this.userUID = this.user.auth.uid;

      firebaseApp.database().ref('/users/' + this.userUID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val().email !== this.userEmail) { //ERROR HERE
          console.log('update the email in database here');
        }
      });

      console.log('User Logged in', this.user, this.userEmail, this.userUID);
      return;
   }

   this.logout();
   console.log('User Not Authenticated', this.user);
 });
}
```

The error is of course at the line where I want to do this comparison:

```
if (snapshot.val().email !== this.userEmail)
```

I know this in JavaScript/typescript is quite annoying and I can't find a way to get my script working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an arrow function it will preserve what `this` refers to

```
firebaseApp.database().ref('/users/' + this.userUID).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.val().email !== this.userEmail) {
        console.log('update the email in database here');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works as expected... Must work on my typescript skills.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript standard trick to solve this is saving `this` into a variable beforehand and then using it, usually `let self = this`.
In TypeScript, the language does this for you when you use fat arrow functions. The compiled JavaScript code will have a regular function but will use a variable named `_this` inside the function, which was initialized to `this` beforehand, instead of `this`.
In short, instead of writing `function (param) { // code }`, use `(param) => { // code }`